# JS Save cookie on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies, dropdown

I'm trying to create a simple form that pops up (i'll be putting the below code into a bootstrap modal) and asks a user to select their location from a drop down list.

I think I'm almost there with this code however the cookie value is always stored as "undefined" when i click submit.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();

    if (!nDays) 
        nDays=1;

    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="setCookie('location', this.value, 365);">
    <select>
        <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>   
</html>
```

Any advice on how I can get it to store the cookie value from the dropdown?

Comment: The value is undefined, because your `<form>` doesn't have a `.value` property. Is it possible to set the cookie via an `onchange` handler on your `<select>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David put it in his comment, form does not return the value of select, so alternatively you can do this:

```js
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
    
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();

    if (!nDays) 
        nDays=1;
  console.log('cookieName: ' + cookieName)
  console.log('coockieValue: ' + cookieValue)
  console.log('nDays: ' + nDays)
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
    // document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
    return false
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="javascript:return setCookie('location', this.querySelector('select').value, 365);">
    <select>
        <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Note**: I put a return in the function so that we can see what is returned in the function parameters